# Display array in tabular form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, iteration

I have an array in this way -

```
arr = ["0.5", " 2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530", " test 1",
       " 0.75", " 2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530", " test 2"]
```

and I want it to be displayed in a tabular form like this -

```
0.5 11:02 test 1
0.75 11:02 test 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = ["0.5", " 2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530", " test 1", " 0.75", " 2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530", " test 2"]

a.each_slice(3) do |x, y, z|
  puts "#{x.strip} #{y[/\d\d:\d\d/]} #{z.strip}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
 arr = ["0.5", " 2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530", " test 1", " 0.75", " 2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530", " test 2"] 

 arr.each_slice(3).map do |x|
   x[1] = Time.parse(x[1]).strftime("%H:%M"); x.map(&:strip) 
 end.map{ |y| puts y.join(' ') }
```

> 0.5 11:02 test 1
>   0.75 11:02 test 2

Answer (score 1):

I joined the elements of `arr` into a string with a space between each element, then scanned the string, saving the results to three capture groups, which produced an array containing two three-elements arrays. Lastly, I joined the three elements of each of the two arrays and printed the result using `puts`.

```
r = /
    (\d+\.\d+)    # match a float in capture group 1
    .+?           # match > 1 of any characters, lazily (?)
    (\d{1,2}:\d2) # match the time in capture group 2
    .+?           # match > 1 of any characters, lazily (?)
    (test\s\d+)   # match 'test' followed by > 1 digits in capture group 3
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

puts arr.join(' ').scan(r).map { |a| a.join(" ") }
```

prints

```
0.5 11:02 test 1
0.75 11:02 test 2
```

The three steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.join(' ')
  #=> "0.5  2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530  test 1  0.75  2016-08-25 11:02:00 +0530  test 2"
b = a.scan(r)
  #=> [["0.5", "11:02", "test 1"],
  #    ["0.75", "11:02", "test 2"]] 
c = b.map { |a| a.join(" ") }
  #=> ["0.5 11:02 test 1", "0.75 11:02 test 2"]
```

Then `puts c` prints the result shown above.